# Performance of COUNT SQL function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, performance, aggregate

I have two choices when writing an SQL statement with the `COUNT` function.

1. `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM <table_name>`
2. `SELECT COUNT(some_column_name) FROM <table_name>`

In terms of performance, what is the best SQL statement?
Can I obtain some performance gain by using option 1?

Comment: I am using MS SQL Server 2005

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Performance should not matter because they do 2 different aggregates

- `COUNT(*)` is all rows, including NULLs
- `COUNT(some_column_name)`, excludes NULL in "`some_column_name`"

See the "[Count(*) vs Count(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221559/)" question for more

Comment: they aren't different in case of primary keys or not null columns.

Comment: @Borys: You'll get the same count. But the primary key will have an index = better. The "not null column" column may not. Of course, it may not matter, but usually it will

Answer (score 4):

Option 2 actually counts all the fields where `some_column_name` is not null. Option 1 counts all the fields where any field is not null. So you might actually get different results out of these two queries. Most of the time you actually want to count all the rows, and then the fastest option, which does not check for any of the fields, is simply `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM ...`

Comment: Count(*) also counts ALL rows, not just rows where any value is not null. And in terms of performance, Count(*) and Count(1) is the same, since the query optimizer recognizes what you are trying to do and generates the same execution plan.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no performance gain in Sql Server.