# Sql COUNT Performance Question

Tags: sql, count, database-performance, sqlanywhere

Structure of Example table:

```
Id, Integer (PK)
Name, Varchar(100)
Description, Text
```

I need to know if exists difference in performance between:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Example;
```

and

```
SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM Example;
```

Or does not exists differences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Differences exist in both performance and the actual resultset

[Performance of COUNT SQL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747990/performance-of-count-sql-function)

Comment: since id is the PK, it is (hopefully!) unlikely it will contain NULLs, which I think is the main difference in results.

Comment: Thank you, I did not find this question.

Comment: @davek - Since `id` is the PK it is not permitted for it to contain nulls. This answer is incorrect. Performance and resultset will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Check the explain plan: does the result come from the table or from meta data (e.g. INFORMATION_SCHEMA)?: The differences are likely to be very minimal.

Answer (score 0):

I would believe that there is a difference; depending on the size of your table, it could be negligible, or it could be significant.

This is probably the slowest:  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Example
This is in the middle:  SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM Example
This would be fastest:  SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Example

Comment: Also depends on what you want to count. Id will probably never be null (if you're doing it right), but count(*) will count only rows with no nulls for example.

Answer (score 0):

Worth reading, but unfortunately in russian.

[COUNT(*), could it be faster?](http://dev.net.ua/blogs/denisreznik/archive/2009/11/17/9031.aspx)

Short story is that `COUNT(*)` is not so efficient as direct access to the `dm_db_partition_stats`.